# Spring AOP for interface and for annotated methods within it

Tags: java, spring, aop

I have service code like this:

```
@Component
public class MyService implements com.xyz.WithSession {

    public void someMethodWhichDoesNotNeedAutorization() {
        // code S1
    }

    @com.xyz.WithAuthorization
    public void someMethodWhichNeedAutorization() {
        // code S2
    }
}
```

and aspect like this:

```
@Aspect
public class MyAspect {

    @Before("target(com.xyz.WithSession)")
    public void adviceBeforeEveryMethodFromClassImplementingWithSession() {
        // code A1
    }

    @Before("target(com.xyz.WithSession) && @annotation(com.xyz.WithAuthorization)")
    public void adviceBeforeWithAuthorizationMethodFromClassImplementingWithSession() {
        // code A2
    }
```

Annotation looks like:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface WithAuthorization{
}
```

- code A1 is called before code S1 -- OK
- code A1 is called before code S2 -- OK
- code A2 isn't called before code S2 -- NOT OK

**What am I doing wrong?**

Code is written in Java 7 with Spring 3.1.3.

## Update

I've tried another way. I use 'Around' advice instead of 'Before' and 'After' to have access to ProceedingJoinPoint. In this advice I check with reflection whether method has annotation 'com.xyz.WithAuthorization' or not:

```
private boolean isAnnotated(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) {
    MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) proceedingJoinPoint.getSignature();
    return signature.getMethod().isAnnotationPresent(com.xyz.WithAuthorization);
}
```

My annotation has '@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)' but I see in debugger that annotation is missing on runtime in the method signature. So the problem still exists.

Comment: Can you add the code of your annotation?

Comment: OK, added in problem description.

Comment: As I said before, please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) in order to make the problem reproduceable if you care to get qualified help. To me it seems very improbable that the annotation should not be there. The compiler does not remove it unless it is buggy. I think the problem is elsewhere, but guessing does not help you. So please ...

Comment: Guessing helped me a lot.
I'm still not 100% sure what was the problem and I cannot provide SSCCE because it's too complex system for me to try recreating case in isolation.
What important I've realized is that MyService is proxied by HttpInvokerServiceExporter and it's probably the reason why annotation isn't captured. So I've solved this problem by implementing MyServiceWithSession interface with all methods from MyService, adding annotations on them, and checking by reflection in aspect whether annotation is present or not.

Comment: Annotations can be made [inheritable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Inherited.html), but only for annotated classes, not for methods and not for interfaces. So if you work with the default Java dynamic proxies in Spring (i.e. against interfaces), it will not work. CGLIB works with classes, that might work. In your example you annotate a method. This does not work either way as explained in the linked Javadoc to `@Inherited`.

Answer (score 4):

In Spring Reference at [this link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html)

***e.g. in Spring reference***

```
@Before("com.xyz.lib.Pointcuts.anyPublicMethod() && @annotation(auditable)")
public void audit(Auditable auditable) {
    AuditCode code = auditable.value();
    // ...
}
```

*the execution of any method defined by the AccountService interface:*

```
execution(* com.xyz.service.AccountService.*(..))
```

*any join point (method execution only in Spring AOP) where the executing method has an @Transactional annotation:*

```
@annotation(org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional)
```

I suggest you to use...

```
@Before("execution(* com.xyz.WithSession.*(..)) && @annotation(authorization)")
public void adviceBeforeWithAuthorizationMethodFromClassImplementingWithSession(WithAuthorization authorization) {
    // code A2
}
```

Comment: I cannot use "execution(* com.xyz.WithSession.*(..))" because method in service are NOT from this empty WithSession interface.

Answer (score 2):

Your second pointcut

```
@Before("target(com.xyz.WithSession) && @annotation(com.xyz.WithAuthorization)")
```

fails in two ways. First the

```
target(com.xyz.WithSession)
```

matches only classes, not methods. So like @Xstian pointed out you should use something along the lines of

```
execution(* com.whatever.MyService.*(..))
```

to match all methods inside the MyService class.

Second problem is the

```
@annotation(com.xyz.WithAuthorization)
```

where the argument should be name that matches the argument name in the advice. So you use `@annotation(someArgumentName)` and then have `com.xyz.WithAuthorization someArgumentName` as your advice methods argument.

Comment: I cannot use "execution(* com.xyz.WithSession.*(..))" because method in service are NOT from this empty WithSession interface.

Comment: @vertti More or less our two solutions are equal :D .. Good!, meaning that is a right way :D

Comment: @nkoder adjusted answer to target `MyService` class instead

Answer (score 1):

Probably your annotation does not have runtime retention:

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface WithAuthorization {}
```

Comment: Sadly, it has runtime retention.

Comment: I tried to recreate the situation with pure AspectJ because I am not a Spring user. There it works, so it should work in Spring too. Maybe you have a configuration problem. Please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) on GitHub so as to make the problem reproduceable.